# BlackBerry: Retrieving the current year, month, day

Tags: java, blackberry

```
//get current date
SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M");
int _currentMonth = Integer.parseInt(monthFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));

SimpleDateFormat yearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY");
int _currentYear = Integer.parseInt(yearFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
```

I'm trying to build a calendar view and I'm starting by retrieving the currrent year and month. However, what is returned is a string, whereas I want a int to use in arrays etc..

The code posted above is giving me an error most likely due to the Integer.parseInt function.

Can I not use it? What is the best way of retrieving the year, month, and day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
int _currentMonth = Integer.parseInt(monthFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));

SimpleDateFormat yearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
int _currentYear = Integer.parseInt(yearFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
```

Change "M" to "MM" and "YYYY" to "yyyy".

Answer (score 1):

You can use calander class to get time

This is for default date means current date :

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("YEAR:"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+" MONTH: "+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1+"  DAY: "+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        //out put as YEAR:2012 MONTH: 01  DAY: 7
```

This is specified date          :

```
Date date1=new Date(Long.parseLong("13259152444455"));//or Date date1=new Date(13259152444455L);
            cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date1);
            System.out.println("YEAR:"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+" MONTH: "+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1+"  DAY: "+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    //      output as YEAR:2390 MONTH: 21  DAY: 2
```

Comment: You don't need to use `Long.parseLong()` to pass a large literal to the `Date()` constructor.  Use the `L` suffix on an integer literal instead, eg: `new Date(13259152444455L);`

Answer (score 0):

duh it does work! I have to use yyyy instead of YYYY. The blackberry documentation had it as YYYY